# grid view validation problem

Tags: asp.net, gridview, validation

in a grid view how can i apply a validator to check if any of grid view rows with check box are checked or not.
i did it using the custom validator  like this but giving the error
"Control 'GridView1' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'gridCheck' cannot be validated. "
following is my code
what should i do please suggest me the alternate

```
protected void gridCheck_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (GridView row in GridView1.Rows) 
        { 
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chek");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
            else args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you debug the application and tell whether check event is raising or not. Means if u checked a check box test it whether it is returning true or not

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add a template field column. Set the gridview to edit templates mode. (in your designer). You can drag and drop controls as usual and set their ids etc. Add your validator control, and set the id.

Comment: my project don't require to turn grid view in edit mode in that case how can i do this. Y direct as i did above doesn't work please let me know what else can i do ?

Comment: I meant "edit Templates" mode, in the designer...I am not talking about enabling "edit button" and all for each row. Click on the gridview's smart tag. Plz check this link if you are finding it difficult finding the smart tag... http://aspnetgoodies.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/grid-view-smart-tag.jpg